# How to run iOS 8.x simulator in Xcode 7.0 (final version)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I recently install Xcode 7.0 final version (not beta). In this Xcode version iOS 9 simulator is available to test the app. But i need to test my app in to iOS 8.x simulator and so on. So, for that i have two option in my knowledge to install older iOS version simulator into Xcode is bellow.

**Option 1:** The one way to install older iOS version of simulator from preference > downloads section and download older iOS version simulator. In this option the problem is it takes too much time to download the simulator SDK. And in between downloading process if internet connection lost for bit of the time then all download progress were lost.
**Option 2:** Copy simulator SDK from older Xcode. I tried this option also but it's not worked for me. After copied simulator SDK from older Xcode i go to Window > Devices and tried to add new simulator but there is no option to add new device of iOS 8.x which simulator SDK i copied from older Xcode.

I found many trial posts but not getting accurate solution or tricks. I regrets in advance if this question found as duplicate.

**Note:** I'm using Xcode 7.0 final version and it's not beta. I already have download option but i want the alternative option.

Comment: Well, the first option is the easiest. As for the second, one possible reason why you can't see the old simulator in the new project is that may be the deployment target of your project is set to iOS 9. Check it.

Comment: Old downloaded simulator does not lost when you update xcode. They are stored in common lib. folder `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/`

Comment: @FreeNickname My iOS Deployment Target is 8.0

Comment: @iOS.Wolf you try first option for older simulators. Copying the simulator might create some issue.

Answer (score 1):

Option 2 is not really supported AFAICS, so go download the Simulators as you outline in Option 1

Comment: I lost all download progress after 6 hours of download and it happened 2-3 times :)

Comment: well can you at least go get xcode7 simulators from a friend or colleague .. sorry about your internet btw :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where 8.x simulator would download but wouldn't install due to a permissions issue. After some searching, I found this answer on Apple developer forum, and it worked for me:

- Go to Terminal
- Type command: sudo /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode

Xcode will be launched. Then you can download simulator that you want.

Note: Once the downloads and installs are complete you should quit Xcode and start it normally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your app with xcode 7 and then install it manually to the simulator from your older xcode version. That's how you do it:

1. Build app for simulator in xcode 7
2. activate your old xcode version with xcode-select
3. run simulator app (from old xcode version) and switch to desired device
4. run 'xcrun simctl install booted /path/to/the/app' with the build from step 1

Make sure you're using a build that is specific for the simulator and not one for a real device. Otherwise the app will crash right away in the simulator. You find the different builds in your 'derived data' folder (check xcode preferences > locations).